# Getting map -> odom transform without using Gmapping

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to get the map -> odom transform which is the pose of the robot in the map frame.
During the execution of my program, I serve a built map to the map server, so I fear that if I have gmapping running with the map server there may be a conflict, ie my program will subscribe to the wrong map topic.

Is there a way to get the map -> odom transform without using gmapping?
Or if I use gmapping will it cause a conflict in my program, if I have an exisiting map on the map server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57902/getting-map--%3E-odom-transform-without-using-gmapping/) by [kachilous](https://answers.ros.org/users/2437/kachilous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If i understand correctly, you only want to localize in a given (static?) map. Have a look at [AMCL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl), which should be exactly what you need.

If you are building your own map dynamically, i think you have to set `use_map_topic` to true and `first_map_only` to false (default).

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can usually remap everything when running gmapping, i.e. the /map topic and possibly the /map frame (via param) for tf. If you do so gmapping will not interfere with other algorithms producing the same kind of data.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kachilous](https://answers.ros.org/users/2437/kachilous/) on 2013-03-12**:
In the map -> odom transform that gmapping provides, where will it get the map data? From the map on the map server or on the map that gmapping has

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-13**:
gmapping make its own map.

**Comment by [kachilous](https://answers.ros.org/users/2437/kachilous/) on 2013-03-13**:
So in calculating the transform map -> odom, instead of using the map that I've loaded on the map server, (which is what I want) it will instead use the map that it has created.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-13**:
gmapping will always create and use its own map.

**Comment by [kachilous](https://answers.ros.org/users/2437/kachilous/) on 2013-03-13**:
So if I want to know the location of the robot in my map that I built with gmapping, would it matter that gmapping uses its own map to calculate the map -> odom transform?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-14**:
gmapping will only give you the position in the map that it builds right now. If you want to localize in a previously recorded map, use something like amcl. See @Ben_S answer for that.